# Why doesn't my negative margin work in IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, margin

I have two stacked divs, where I want the content from the top div to flow over onto the bottom div.  Using a negative bottom margin on the content wrapper, I was able to achieve this in all browsers except IE 7, where instead of flowing over the bottom div, the content gets cut-off/overlapped by it.

I'm looking for an explanation of what exactly is happening here, and potential fixes.

**Complete HTML example:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Negative Margin Test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.2.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">

<style type="text/css">

.container {
 width: 800px;
 background: none;
 position:relative; 
}
.container-mid{
 background:#F00;/**/
 border:dashed thick #090;
 width:100%;
}
.container-bottom{
 background:#FF0;/**/
 border:dashed thick #090;
 width:100%;
 height: 200px;
}
.container-inner{
 width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-bottom:-200px;/**/

}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">


    <div class="container-mid">

        <div class="container-inner">

            <div class="content">       

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet bibendum tortor. Etiam at diam vitae mauris venenatis varius. Nam nec mauris ut ligula dictum fringilla a accumsan diam. Fusce ac mauris in lacus venenatis bibendum non eget nisl. In quis pretium dolor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam at quam et velit faucibus cursus. Aenean ut augue id augue suscipit condimentum sed eu est. Pellentesque commodo ipsum nec ligula aliquet a lobortis augue pharetra. Curabitur pretium luctus posuere. Proin id nisi sed lectus commodo porta. Fusce leo augue, lacinia eu tincidunt sed, faucibus at turpis. Aenean ut mi nulla. Duis orci urna, euismod quis mollis interdum, pharetra quis enim. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Morbi gravida eleifend ante ac hendrerit. Nunc ultricies tellus mauris.</p>
                <br />
                <br />
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet bibendum tortor. Etiam at diam vitae mauris venenatis varius. Nam nec mauris ut ligula dictum fringilla a accumsan diam. Fusce ac mauris in lacus venenatis bibendum non eget nisl. In quis pretium dolor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam at quam et velit faucibus cursus. Aenean ut augue id augue suscipit condimentum sed eu est. Pellentesque commodo ipsum nec ligula aliquet a lobortis augue pharetra. Curabitur pretium luctus posuere. Proin id nisi sed lectus commodo porta. Fusce leo augue, lacinia eu tincidunt sed, faucibus at turpis. Aenean ut mi nulla. Duis orci urna, euismod quis mollis interdum, pharetra quis enim. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Morbi gravida eleifend ante ac hendrerit. Nunc ultricies tellus mauris.</p>
                <br />
                <br />
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet bibendum tortor. Etiam at diam vitae mauris venenatis varius. Nam nec mauris ut ligula dictum fringilla a accumsan diam. Fusce ac mauris in lacus venenatis bibendum non eget nisl. In quis pretium dolor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam at quam et velit faucibus cursus. Aenean ut augue id augue suscipit condimentum sed eu est. Pellentesque commodo ipsum nec ligula aliquet a lobortis augue pharetra. Curabitur pretium luctus posuere. Proin id nisi sed lectus commodo porta. Fusce leo augue, lacinia eu tincidunt sed, faucibus at turpis. Aenean ut mi nulla. Duis orci urna, euismod quis mollis interdum, pharetra quis enim. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Morbi gravida eleifend ante ac hendrerit. Nunc ultricies tellus mauris.</p>

            </div><!-- end .content -->

        </div><!-- end .container-inner -->

    </div><!-- end .container-mid -->

    <div class="container-bottom"></div>

  <!-- end .container --></div>


</body>
</html>
```

**In IE8:** (Results same with Chrome/FFox/etc...)
[image]

**In IE 7:** (Tested with IE8->Developer Tools->IE7 Mode)
[image]

As you can see, overflowing content gets overlapped by the yellow div.

See my [live example](http://tests.appgrinders.com/negmargintest.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `position:relative;` on `.container-inner` so it explicitly has a higher stacking order, which should place it above.

```
.container-inner { position:relative; }
```

I documented this bug [here](http://work.arounds.org/issue/2/negative-margin-causes-overflow-or-clipping/).

Comment: This works! - But could you explain the stacking order issue a little more?  How does position=relative change the order?  Is this something that could have been done with z-index, or is it different?

Comment: `position:relative` gives an element higher stacking order than a static positioned element. IE's entire stacking order algorithm is broken so it does not obey and render like Chrome/Fx do.. so we have to explicitly do it. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html

Comment: Thanks a lot- I've bookmarked your blog, sure to be useful... (Bounty yours as soon as I can)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to explicitly set the `overflow` CSS property.  IE 7 has a number of defaults that are different than most browsers.  See: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Try:

```
.container-inner{
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom:-200px;/**/
    overflow: visible;/**/
}
```

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work. The overflow seems to have been fine all along, but as meder points out it was getting overlapped in the stacking order.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to only use a single div.  Set the background to be yellow, with a repeat-x background of red which is 200px high

```
.container {
    background: url('red_back.png') repeat-x 0 0 yellow;
    }
```

Comment: The red/yellow divs are only for illustrative purposes.  It's the underlying bug we're trying to tackle.